# Laravel Dompdf taking too long to download pdf

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, dompdf

I want to make a pdf invoice from blade template using Dompdf in Laravel 5.5.

The problem is when clicking on the download button the page is loading and after ~3 min i the pdf starts downloading.

Why is it taking so long?

the download link

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.download-invoice', $order->OrderID) }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Download Invoice</a>
```

web route:

```
Route::get('/order/download-invoice/{OrderID}', 'Admin\AdminOrderController@downloadOrderInvoice')->name('admin.download-invoice');
```

a simple template (invoice.blade.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other 
head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Invoice</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
   <div>{{ $invoice->InvoiceTitle }} </div>
</body>
</html>
```

donwload invoice controller function:

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;
public function downloadOrderInvoice($OrderID){  

    $invoice = Invoice::where('OrderID', $OrderID)->first();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice.invoice', compact('invoice'))->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');

    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
}
```

What i did wrong? Did i miss something?

**UPDATE**

clear the header and using EXTERNAL CDN bootstrap works.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Why is not using the local bootstrap using asset???

```
<link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other 
head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Invoice</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" media="screen">
</head>
remove this stuff

Comment: $pdf = \PDF::loadview('invoice.invoice',$invoice);
        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');

Comment: "Undefined variable: invoice" if using $pdf = \PDF::loadview('invoice.invoice',$invoice);

Comment: Is that error thrown quickly? Or does it take 3 minutes? If it's quickly, the problem is in the PDF generation. If takes long, it's in your query.

Comment: $invoice = Invoice::where('OrderID', $OrderID)->first();
are you sure you will get data in this query?
if data is empty then you need to use conditions

Comment: yes. I get the data from the query. Removing the <head> section works really fast but i need the hdader for styles

Comment: I see you use Bootstrap styles. Note that DOMPDF (or any PDF generator for that matter) only supports the CSS 2.1 spec, which means a lot of Bootstrap styles probably won't even render. There's plenty of good invoice pdf css templates online, pick one you like and work with that. Might even fix the problem..

Comment: don't use bootstrap css

Comment: that`s good to know. thx @Maulik

Comment: adding external bootstrap from CDN workd fine. Why is not working with local bootstrap????? `<link href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/631
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1231
see this links

Comment: i was too, it took too long for the dompdf to render in php artisan development mode (artisan serve) but when i run it on the fly using server / xampp , it works fine...